# Checkbox value in wpf treeview is not equal to value of bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview

I have a `treeview` in a wpf form that initially binds correctly but certain combinations of `checking and unchecking` items in the tree cause the `binding` to fail to hold.

Here is the property;

```
const string HAS_ACCESS = "HasAccess";

 public bool? HasAccess
 {
    get
      {
         return hasAccess;
      }
    set
      {
         if (hasAccess == value) return;
           if(!AllowUpdate(value)) return;
              //Debug.WriteLine("{0}  tried to set hasAccess to a value of {1} D = {2}, A = {3}, u = {4}, AllowChange = {5}, I = {6}", myPermission.Name, value, descendantChanged, ancestorChanged, userInstigatedChange, AllowUpdate(value), isInitialising);
            ResetChangeBools();
            hasAccess = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("HasAccess = {0}", HasAccess);
            isInitialising = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged(HAS_ACCESS);
      }
   }
```

This is the xaml;

```
   <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
             IsThreeState="true"
             Content="{Binding MyPermission.Name}"
             Click="CheckBox_Clicked"
             IsChecked="{Binding HasAccess, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I must stress that the correct value for `HasAccess` is displayed when the `treeview` is `initialised` and does update when changed MOST OF THE TIME but if I check a child item in the `treeview` (that correctly checks its parent), `uncheck` its parent (which correctly unchecks its children) then recheck the initial child element the parent no longer checks. I included the Debug.writeline to check that the values were being correctly set and although I can see the correct values in the Output window they are not shown in the checkbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem Med.Amine.Touil was almost there. There is a bug with the checkbox. It was losing its binding when the binding mode was set to OneWay but I could not make the binding TwoWay because I did not want a value change to directly change the underlying dataContext. By making the binding TwoWay and the UpdateSourceTrigger = Explicit I got the behaviour I wanted.

```
IsChecked="{Binding HasAccess, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your binding mode to TwoWay  `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: I attempted this but it did not work, the problem is that the value from my viewmodel is not being set in the control. Oneway should be able to show this.

Comment: @monkeyTrainer , Did you try a simple example. i mean remove your business logic from the setter(just do hasAccess = value and Raise your property changed event) and in your VM constructor initalize this HasAccess property to see if binding goes fine or not